# Why can´t i change the color of text lines? Change plain text into a HTML <td>

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, colors

I'm trying to change the color of text lines containing "Accepted" to green and all others to red but when i upload my file all the lines are green. What am I doing wrong? I really don't know why the else statement is not read.

[image]

```js
document.getElementById("openFile").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    
    fr.onload = function(){ 
        document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent = this.result;  
        let lines = document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent.split('\n');
        let parser ='';       
        for(let line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
            if (lines[line].substring(0,3)==="ACK"){
                parser += lines[line].substring(0,3) + "\t"  + lines[line].substring(49,108).trim() + "\t" + lines[line].substring(109,115) + "\t" + lines[line].substring(149,159).replace(/as/gi,"\tAccepted").replace(/rj/gi,"\tRejected") + '\n';
            }
            else if (lines[line].substring(0,3)==="MSG"){
                parser += lines[line].substring(0,3) + "\t" + lines[line].substring(35,159).replace(/,/,"").trim() + '\n';
            }
        }       
        document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent = parser;
        
        if (parser.includes("Accepted")){
            document.getElementById("fileContents").style.color = "#00FF00";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("fileContents").style.color = "#FF0000";
        }
    }  
    fr.readAsText(file);
},false)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Parser</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="openFile"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br> 
    <pre id="fileContents"></pre>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

After the suggestion of @aptriangle I tried to replace replace each line of text generated by an HTML element, in this case each substring should be a . I'm stuck on this and I can not make the necessary change. Can someone give me a help? Thank you in advance.

```js
document.getElementById("openFile").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    
    fr.onload = function(){ 
        document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent = this.result;  
        
        let lines = document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent.split('\n');
        let parser =''; 
        
        for(let line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
            if (lines[line].substring(0,3)==="ACK"){
                
                var sub1 = lines[line].substring(0,3) + '\t';
                var sub2 = lines[line].substring(49,108) + '\t';
                var sub3 = lines[line].substring(109,115) + '\t';
                var sub4 = lines[line].substring(149,lines.length).replace(/as/gi,"\tAccepted").replace(/rj/gi,"\tRejected").trim() + '\n';
                
                var tdata1,tdata2,tdata3,tdata4 = document.createElement("td");
                tdata1.createTextNode(sub1);
                tdata2.createTextNode(sub2);
                tdata3.createTextNode(sub3);
                tdata4.createTextNode(sub4);
                parser += tdata1 + tdata2
                    + tdata3 + tdata4;
                var element = document.getElementById("fileContents");
                element.appendChild(parser);
            }
            else if (lines[line].substring(0,3)==="MSG"){
                var sub1 = lines[line].substring(0,3) + '\t';
                var sub2 = lines[line].substring(35,lines.length).replace(/,/,'').trim() + '\n';
                
                parser += sub1 + sub2;
            }     
        }
        document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent = parser;
        
         
    }  
    fr.readAsText(file);
},false)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Parser</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="openFile" class="btn btn-light" type="file" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="header" class="font-weight-bold"></div>
    <pre id="fileContents" class="font-weight-bold"></pre>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I still can't put paragraphs when i upload the code...now what am i doing wrong? Sorry to bother but i really can't figure it out.

```js
document.getElementById("openFile").addEventListener("change", function(){
    let file = this.files[0];
    let fr = new FileReader();
    
    fr.onload = function(){ 
        let content = document.getElementById("fileContents");
        content.textContent = this.result;  
        
        let lines = content.textContent.split('\n');
        let parser = ''; 
        let para;
        
        for(let line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
            
            para = document.createElement("p")
            para.innerHTML = lines[line];
            
            if (lines[line].substring(0,3)==="ACK"){    
                let sub1 = lines[line].substring(0,3) + '\t';
                let sub2 = lines[line].substring(49,108) + '\t';
                let sub3 = lines[line].substring(109,115) + '\t';
                let sub4 = lines[line].substring(149,lines.length).replace(/as/gi,"\tAccepted").replace(/rj/gi,"\tRejected") + '\n';
                
                parser += sub1 + sub2 + sub3 + sub4;
            }
            else if (lines[line].substring(0,3)==="MSG"){
                let sub1 = lines[line].substring(0,3) + '\t';
                let sub2 = lines[line].substring(35,lines.length).replace(/,/,'').trim() + '\n';
                
                parser += sub1 + sub2;    
            } 
            content.appendChild(para);
        }
        content.textContent = parser;
    }  
    fr.readAsText(file);
},false)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Parser</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="openFile" class="btn btn-light" type="file" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <pre id="fileContents" class="font-weight-bold"></pre>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a typo in the color declaration of the else stamtent.

 document.getElementById("fileContents").style.color = "FF0000";
you are missing the hash mark on the color - so change it to the following

 document.getElementById("fileContents").style.color = "#FF0000"; Thanks @Barmar

Comment: It is still not working but thanks for the warning.

Comment: The code suggests you are changing the color of the whole `fileContents`, not just a single line?

Comment: @ThomasHirsch how can i do it then?

Comment: As it is, you are telling the javascript that if the text "Accepted" is anywhere in the document it should color the whole thing green. If you want to choose a color line by line, you need to add an html element for each line and set a color for each element. If you want the lines to be on separate lines in the output, you could add "<p style="color:#FF0000">" to the beginning of the line and "</p>" to the end of the line. If you don't want them on different lines, replace p with span.

Comment: @aptriangle i also tried with  "parser.endsWith("Accepted")" and it didnt´t work.
What do you mean adding "<p style="color:#FF0000">"? I will post a picture to show you what i expect.

Comment: document.getElementById("fileContents").style.color sets the color of the html element that contains **all of your text**. It is doing what you tell it to do. If you want each line to be a different color, you must put each line in a **different** html element and set the color of **each** html element to the color that line should be. Adding a paragraph element to every line will allow you to set the color of each line individually.

Comment: @aptriangle i will put my code after i tried your sugestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle that shows a working split and style: https://jsfiddle.net/4qv3h0xp/

```
var element;
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  element = document.createElement("p");
  element.innerHTML = split[i];
  if (split[i].indexOf("Accepted") == -1) {
    element.style.color = "#00FF00";
  }
  else {
    element.style.color = "#FF0000";
  }
  output.appendChild(element);
}
```

It creates a new element for every line and appends the elements to the parent, instead of styling the parent.

Comment: I  still can put the paragraphs @aptriangle. I posted my last attempt.

Comment: Setting the textContent overwrites all of the paragraphs you previously added.

Comment: I added the <p> tags, but what I want and replace the text generated by <p> tags, I do not want to add more paragraphs in front of the <pre> tag.

Comment: If you want to style text differently than the text around it, you have to have it put the text you want to style inside tags, like <p>. You can insert them before a different element by using insertBefore.